# java regular expressions regex

Tags: java, regex, expression

I have problem with extracting data from website.
Im trying to get name of company and price its: **SYGNITY** and **8,40**

```
<a class="link" href="http://www.money.pl/gielda/spolki-gpw/PLCMPLD00016.html">SYGNITY</a>

        </td>
        <td class="ac"><a href="javascript: OO('SGN','2015-10-01')"><img width="12" height="11" src="http://static1.money.pl/i/gielda/chart.gif" title="Pokaż wykres" alt="Pokaż wykres" /></a></td>
                        <td class="al">SGN</td>
                    <td class="ar">8,40</td>
```

I tried to use this pattern but it doesnt work:

```
String expr = "<a class=\"link\" href=\"(.+?)\">(.+?)</a>(.+?)<td class=\"ar\">(.+?)</td> ";
```

any advices?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML, use a proper HTML parser like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: One of the highest voted answers on the site - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1541619

Answer (score 1):

### Using JSoup parser

You should use a html parser like JSoup since regex is not a good idea to parse html.

You can do something like this:

```
String htmlString = "YOUR HTML HERE";
Document document=Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
Element element=document.select("a[href=http://www.money.pl/gielda/spolki-gpw/PLCMPLD00016.html]").first();
System.out.println(element.text()); //SYGNITY

element=document.select("td[class=ar]").first();
System.out.println(element.text()); //8,40
```

### Using regex

If you still want to use a regex, then you could use a regex like below and grab the content from capturing groups:

```
PLCMPLD00016.html">(.*?)<\/a>|"ar">(.*?)<\/td>
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG8fJ2/1)**

```
String htmlString = "YOUR HTML HERE"
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("PLCMPLD00016.html">(.*?)<\\/a>|"ar">(.*?)<\\/td>");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlString );
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```